# Haskell - testDatabase is applied to one argument but its type "database" has none.

Tags: functional-programming, haskell

My database should contain up to 25 of these data entries. At the moment, i only have these but I'm receiving an error message of:

> testDatabase is applied to one argument but its type "database" has none.

Or something close to that.

My actual code is the following:

```
testDatabase :: Database
testDatabase = testDatabase [
("Casino Royale", ["Daniel Craig", "Eva Green", "Judi Dench"], 2006, ["Garry", "Dave", "Zoe", "Kevin", "Emma"]),
("Cowboys & Aliens", ["Harrison Ford", "Daniel Craig", "Olivia Wilde"], 2011, ["Bill", "Jo", "Garry", "Kevin", "Olga", "Liz"]),     
("Catch Me If You Can", ["Leonardo DiCaprio", "Tom Hanks"], 2002, ["Zoe", "Heidi", "Jo", "Emma", "Liz", "Sam", "Olga", "Kevin", "Tim"])]
```

Comment: try removing the "testDatabase" just to the right of the equal sign, i.e., `testDatabase = [("Casino Royale"...` . The compiler is interpreting testDatabase as a function with no parameters because of the type signature -- then it looks like you are calling the function: `testDatabase (your-list-as-a-parameter)`

Answer (score 2):

This is the same as my comment above but Just in case you want to mark the question as answered...

Try removing the "testDatabase" just to the right of the equal sign, i.e., `testDatabase = [("Casino Royale"...` . The compiler is interpreting testDatabase as a function with no parameters because of the type signature -- then it looks like you are calling the function: `testDatabase (your-list-as-a-parameter)`